# Jquery асоциативный многоуровневый массив

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть вот такой html

```
<label for="val-1" class="m-r-sm">
    <input type="checkbox" name="attributes" value="1" data-attribute-name="size" id="val-1" class="js-product-attributes" >10
</label>
<label for="val-2" class="m-r-sm">
    <input type="checkbox" name="attributes" value="2" data-attribute-name="color" id="val-2" class="js-product-attributes" >Red
</label>
```

Таких чекбоксов n-ное количество

и вот такой js код

```
        var $combination = {};
        $('.js-product-attributes:checked').each(function (i, el) {
            $combination[$(el).data('attribute-name')] = {};
        });

        console.log($combination);
```

В итоге получаю

```
Object {Size: Object, Color: Object}
    Color: Object
    Size:Object
    __proto__: Object
```

Сам вопрос, как элементы этого обьекта добавить массив значений выделенных чекбоксов у которых `data-attribute-name` соответствует названию элемента в обьекте. Тоесть к `Object.color` добавить все выделенные чекбоксы у которых `data-attribute-name="color"`.
Спасибо!

Comment: Object.color это масив?

Answer (score 0):

Так?

```js
var $combination = {};
$('.js-product-attributes').each(function (i, el) {
    $combination[$(el).data('attribute-name')] = {};
});
function PuchCheck(){
    let color = $('.js-product-attributes[data-attribute-name = color]:checked'),
        size = $('.js-product-attributes[data-attribute-name = size]:checked');
    $combination.color = color;
    $combination.size = size;
    console.log($combination.color.length+' '+$combination.size.length);
    $($combination.color).parent().css({'color':'red'});
    $($combination.size).parent().css({'color':'blue'});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="val-1" class="m-r-sm">
    <input type="checkbox" name="attributes" value="1" data-attribute-name="size" id="val-1" class="js-product-attributes" >10
</label>
<label for="val-2" class="m-r-sm">
    <input type="checkbox" name="attributes" value="2" data-attribute-name="color" id="val-2" class="js-product-attributes" >Red
</label>
<label for="val-3" class="m-r-sm">
    <input type="checkbox" name="attributes" value="2" data-attribute-name="color" id="val-3" class="js-product-attributes" >Grey
</label>
<label for="val-4" class="m-r-sm">
    <input type="checkbox" name="attributes" value="2" data-attribute-name="color" id="val-4" class="js-product-attributes" >Green
</label>
<button onclick="PuchCheck()">Push</button>
```